# Webpack output two bundles: source is node_modules vs src?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

My project structure:

```
/src
  /module_1
  /module_2
  /module_3
  /...  <-- half a dozen other directories
/node_modules
  /obscure_1
  /obscure_2
  /obscure_3
  /...  <-- half a million other directories
```

Is there a way to automatically have Webpack (3.x) output two bundles:

- Only files from `/src`
- Only files imported from `/src`, but from `/node_modules`

What I've done in the past is manually select the 3-4 main packages used by my project (in `/src`), and packaged those separately (by excluding them from the main bundle via the config's `externals` block). Is it possible to fully automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout how [`CommonChunkPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) works, it should solve your problem.

You can specify that all the modules that comes from `node_modules` will be in the vendors chunk with passing that config to it:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "vendor",
    minChunks: function(module){
      return module.context && module.context.includes("node_modules");
    }
})
```

Comment: Won't this bundle *all* of `node_modules`, though, instead of just the packages being required from `/src`?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira everything that is not required is completely ignored

Comment: All the packages that are required from the entry point and comes from node-modules will be there